# Change dnsmasq from .dev to .local

Tags: mac, dnsmasq

I originally tried asking this question on apple.stackexchange.com, but I think it may be a bit beyond the scope of being just for macs (and therefore more of a server config issue), so had no response. Can anyone here suggest anything? Thanks.

I have followed these [instructions for setting up a dnsmasq](http://passingcuriosity.com/2013/dnsmasq-dev-osx/) on my Mac.

I originally set it up to use `.dev`, but now I want to change `.dev` to `.local`. However, when I try using `.local` instead, it doesn't work.

Even when I uninstall dnsmasq, and unload and remove the settings using launchtl, requests to `.dev` still work, and `.local` don't. I have tried restarting, too.

Are these settings set automatically by apple somewhere else and being used (and always have been)?

And how can I change to using `.local`?

Comment: `.local` has been co-opted for use by auto-config (bonjour, avahi, ...).  I would recommend not using it for DNS.  The traditional name would be `localnet`, but `lan` is often used.

Comment: [What you are trying to do is wrongheaded and will cause you difficulty.  There are over 12 years of widely-shared Mac experience saying not to do this.  Learn from it.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-use-domain-names-that-you-own.html)

Comment: Yes thanks for that, I didn't realise that local was used by other processes